# Where can I find i18n files of Meteor app on production server?

Tags: meteor

I use TAPi18n package and translation JSON files are stored in i18n folder of my Meteor app. When I deploy app on production server with Meteor Up, I can't find translation JSON files on the server. I need it because I need to update the files from app - read and write into them.

So where can I find i18n folder and i18n files of Meteor app on production server?

Answer (score 0):

I have found where i18n files are stored:

```
find /opt/aleno/ -name '*.i18n.*'

/opt/aleno/app/programs/server/app/home/elfoslav/projects/web/meteor/aleno.me/app/i18n/de.i18n.js
/opt/aleno/app/programs/server/app/home/elfoslav/projects/web/meteor/aleno.me/app/i18n/en.i18n.js
```

But they are just compiled JS files and they contain something like:

```
(function(){var _ = Package.underscore._,
    package_name = "project",
    namespace = "project";

if (package_name != "project") {
    namespace = TAPi18n.packages[package_name].namespace;
}
// integrate the fallback language translations
translations = {};
translations[namespace] = {"SMS Bestätigung (**date**, **time**, **peopleCount**)":"SMS confirmation (**date**, **time**, **peopleCount**)","$
TAPi18n._loadLangFileObject("en", translations);

})();
```